# Error while running make peer command from fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Im following this link https://openblockchain.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Setup/JAVAChaincode/ , to run my sample java chaincode.

When i run make peer from vagrant , it shows the following error.

[image: make peer]

When i list peer i could find the files inside it .

[[image: list peer [2]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use `sudo` to build the peer.  (the issue you have is that GOPATH is not defined for root so when you run `sudo` Go cannot find the fabric source)

More importantly, you are working off a very old version of the documentation.  Many things have changed since.  You should be looking at https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io instead.  Also, there is no need to actually build Fabric yourself - you can download and install Docker images for the current version ( https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/install.html ).